# python - how to display time as epoch?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to display the current time as an epoch in python to pass as a variable into some code how do I go about doing that?

ie. `1458410416`

Every method of

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime()
```

gives human readable values.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Import the `time` library, and then use this code:

```
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())
1458410651.0
```

`time.mktime` converts  a `datetime` to a Unix epoch timestamp.

Comment: great!  I actually found this the same time I posted and did this `epoch_time = int(time.time())`

Comment: @whoisearth That's a good solution that I didn't know about, but I don't think that could be used if your desired time to convert isn't the current time.

Answer (score 14):

There is a built-in function in the `time` module:

```
import time

seconds = time.time()
```

There are many functions in the `time` module for seconds since the Epoch, time tuples, etc.  I would recommend that you check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/time.html).