# How to increase timestamp string to timestamp with new year, month, day Python datetime?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to write a function that takes in a string representing timestamp, then change the year, month and day of that timestamp but not the actual time. Then I want to return the resulting timestamp as a string. I'm having some trouble with the conversion, since I think I need to convert in the following sequence: string -> timestamp -> date -> timestamp -> string. I've read through the datetime library, but I'm having some trouble with this conversion. Any assistance, would be much appreciated!

Function inputs would look like this:

```
def change_date(string: timestamp, string: new_date)
    #timestamp: string formatted like 1601403951777
    #new_date: string formatted like YYYY-MM-DD
```

For instance timestamp 1601403951777 is Tuesday, September 29, 2020.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from datetime import datetime
def change_date(dt):
    #timestamp: string
    #new_date: string formatted like YYYY-MM-DD
    d= datetime.fromisoformat(dt)
    new_date = d.strftime(('%Y-%m-%d'))
    print(new_date)

dt = str(datetime.now())
print(dt)
change_date(dt)
```

output

```
2021-06-09 16:15:58.421486
2021-06-09
```

Comment: Just one difference here. The timestamp is a timestamp string, say like 1601403951777 which represents Tuesday, September 29, 2020. That would be my timestamp string. (https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105232/python-how-to-display-time-as-epoch

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [`.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) method of datetime objects:

```py
def change_date(string: timestamp, string: new_date):
    source_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
    year, month, date = [int(i) for i in new_date.split('-')]
    return f"{source_dt.replace(year=year, month=month, date=date):...}"
```

where `{:...}` is the format you need.

Comment: `int(timestamp) / 1000` because you need to pass a float that is total seconds to `fromtimestamp()`